# Selecting distinct values in a mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my mysql table:

Table League (userid and lid are primary keys):

```
*userid*  *lid*     rank    win     loss     streak  score
---------------------------------------------------------
    2       1        1       2       0         2      10
    2       3        2       1       1         1       5
    5       1        2       1       1         1       5
```

I'm trying to select the users with the top score only once. For example since userid 2 is in league (lid) 1 and 3, only his top score will be selected in the query. So in that case the row with score 10 would be selected since that's the users top score from both league 1 and 3. The row with lid 3 will not be selected.

So the query results should look like this:

```
userid  lid     rank    win     loss     streak  score
---------------------------------------------------------
  2      1       1       2       0         2      10
  5      1       2       1       1         1       5
```

As you can see userid 2 with lid 3 was not in the result because the score 10 from lid 1 was grater than score 5 from league 3. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT l.userid, u.username, l.lid, l.rank, l.win, l.loss, l.streak, l.score
    FROM (SELECT userid, MAX(score) AS MaxScore
              FROM League 
              GROUP BY userid) q
        INNER JOIN League l
            ON q.userid = l.userid
                AND q.MaxScore = l.score
        INNER JOIN users u
            ON l.userid = u.userid
```

Comment: this worked perfectly. Is there a way to add another join to this? I have a table called users and it has two columns, userid and username. I'm trying to link the userid from table League to the username of table users via the userid.

Comment: @user962449 I've updated the answer to reflect the additional join.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table t1
WHERE t1.score = (SELECT MAX(t2.score)
  FROM table t2
  WHERE t1.userid = t2.userid)
```

This will display ties, don't know if you want those or not.

Comment: where t2.userid = t2.userid ?? and I think the question is about the max score

Comment: I thought he wanted the max score?

Comment: yeah I want the max score, no ties. I just want to display the top score from one league per user.

Comment: I zoned out for a second and went MIN because I was thinking of rank, but then I still wrote score... fixed, thanks both

Comment: I don't get this query. I only have one table, but you show two tables in your example.

Comment: I only use one table, I use it twice though, so I name it different things to separate context.

Comment: This produce duplicate userId for a user with same score in several ligues

Comment: I noted that in the answer, I said it would display ties. If you tell us how you want tiebreaking done then say so, otherwise you're just asking to be spoonfed code.

Answer (score 0):

Here the simplest solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM League t1 
WHERE 
  t1.lig = (SELECT t2.lig
        FROM League t2
        WHERE t2.userid = t1.userid
        ORDER BY score desc
        LIMIT 1
     )
```